# Connecting a switch to a VDSL2 model causes upload speeds to go to 0

Tags: router, switch, bridge, adsl, dsl

My network configuration has my main router connected to a secondary router which is in bridge mode, and I have a computer connected via ethernet to that secondary router.

If the connection between my main router and secondary router is through an inline coupler, the speeds on the computer are as expected. However, when the connection is thorugh an [unmanaged switch](http://www.netis-systems.com/en/products/unmanagement-switch/115.html), the download speed is unaffected, but the upload speed is basically 0 (speedtest.net can't even finish the upload portion of the test).

The switch has only started causing problems when I switched from the main modem being an ADSL modem from my ISP to a VDSL2 modem.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you checked for duplex mismatches on machines connected to the unmanaged switch?

Comment: @MadHatter, my secondary router is running Tomato and my main one is a Pace 5168N. How can I check this?

Comment: I have no idea; you will need to refer to the manuals in each case.   You will also need to find out how to check the switch; even though it's unmanaged, most switches can tell you this from the idiot lights, with a bit of button pressing.  I'm afraid this is one very good reason most of us will no longer use unmanaged switches.

Comment: Sounds like modem and switch are not fully compatible. Have you tried another switch?